# How to round to specific values in Python

Tags: python, function, rounding

I am working on an algorithm to automatically create character sheets for a roleplaying game. In the game, you have attributes which you put points into to increase them. However, at a certain value it takes 2 points to increase the value of the actual attribute by 1. You start of with a certain number of points, and each attribute has a value of 1 by default

I have a program that randomly assigns the points, however I am stuck as to how I then change these values (that are in a dictionary) to round down when necessary.

For example, if I put 3 points in "strength", thats fine, I get a "strength" value of 3 (including tha base 1). However, if I put 4 points in, I still should only have a value of 4. It should take 5 points (plus the base 1) in order to get a value of 5. It then takes another 2 points to get a value of 6, 3 points to get a value of 7 and 3 points to get a value of 8.

The code I am currently using to assign the attibutes looks like this:

```
attributes = {}
row1 = ['strength', 'intelligence', 'charisma']
row2 = ['stamina', 'willpower']
row3 = ['dexterity', 'wits', 'luck']

def assignRow(row, p): # p is the number of points you have to assign to each row
    rowValues = {}
    for i in range(0, len(row)-1):
        val = randint(0, p)
        rowValues[row[i]] = val + 1
        p -= val
    rowValues[row[-1]] = p + 1
    return attributes.update(rowValues)

assignRow(row1, 7)
assignRow(row2, 5)
assignRow(row3, 3)
```

What I want is just a simple function that takes the dictionary "attributes" as a parameter, and converts the number of points each attribute has to the proper value it should be.

i.e. `"strength": 4` stays as `"strength": 4`, but `"wits": 6"` goes down to `"wits": 5"`, and `"intelligence: 9` goes down to `"intelligence: 7"`.

I'm somewhat new to using dictionaries and so the ways I would normally approach this:

```
def convert(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] <= 4:
            list[i] = list[i]
        if list[i] in (5, 6):
            list[i] -= 1
        if list[i] in (7, 8):
            list[i] -= 2
        if list[i] in (9, 10):
            list[i] = 6
        if list[i] in (11, 12, 13):
            list[i] = 7
        else:
            list[i] = 8
```

Not efficient or pretty but still a solutuion. However, you can't just loop over indexes in a dictionary so I am not entirely sure how to go about something like this.

General explanation or function would be appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate that as a beginner, you took the time and trouble to make your own solution before asking. No matter how inefficient it is, you will be able to understand other solutions much better and you have grown as a programmer already.

Comment: That being said, don't use the name of the builtin name `list`. It is conventional to at least use `list_`. It's not that your code will immediately break, but you won't be able to call the builtin function to convert things to lists anymore. Also, the line `row = list` does pretty much nothing useful. Just call the input parameter `row` and kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks, I've updated the program

Comment: You are using `list` in the sample of `convert` as well. However, in future, do not change the code of a question, especially if there are already answers present, unless you make a mistake copying it over. Improving your question as you go invalidates existing answers and makes it generally harder to help you.

Comment: Ah okay, will refrain form doing so.

Comment: Thanks. I know that thats the initial knee-jerk response everyone has when simple improvements are suggested.

Comment: What is the formula for your conversion? Is it an exponential increase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that [bisection](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html) algo suits your needs pretty well - points to "invest" is always sorted and defined. Create array with reference points and you're good to without bunch of `if`s:

```
>>> from bisect import bisect
>>> points_to_invest = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 13]
>>> bisect(points_to_invest, 1)
1
>>> bisect(points_to_invest, 4)
4
>>> bisect(points_to_invest, 5)
4
>>> bisect(points_to_invest, 6)
5
```

This approach will give you way easier maintainability for future

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! What is the best way to put it into the function format I need?

Comment: Mb I've misunderstood, but I thought that main problem here was to get the attribute values. If you get this idea, rest is simple - iterate through `attribute_dict.items()` and get values by bisect. If you've tried this and still have issues - pls, create new question on stackoverflow, its way better that bloating single one with elaborations

Comment: Sorry, no it works perfectly now, I just threw it under the first two lines in the question below.

Comment: @FreddieR. Combine this answer with a list comprehension. Replace the entire loop `for i in range(len(list)):` with just `return [bisect(points_to_invest, x) for x in list]`. Use the return value of that (now one-line function to replace the input list.

Comment: Well this isn't a list it's a dictionary, so instead I used `for key, value in attributes.items():`, suggested in the answer below, but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the elements by using `dictionary.items()`
You can then modify your convert function:

```
def convert(attributes):
    for key, value in attributes.items():
        # do your conversion on value here
        if value <= 4:
            continue # do nothing for this element
        elif value in (5, 6):
            value -= 1
        elif value in (7, 8):
            value -= 2
        elif value in (9, 10):
            value = 6
        elif value in (11, 12, 13):
            value = 7
        else:
            value = 8

        # to replace the value in the dictionary you can use
        attributes[key] = new_value
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! (Although on the last line you have to change it to be `attributes[key] = value`, since new_value doesn't exist anywhere else)

Answer (score 1):

A bit less space then your "convert" function, though still manual labor:

```
p_to_v = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:4, 6:5, 7:5, 8:6} # 'translator' dict, fill up further
input = {'strength':6, 'wits':8} # dict with stats and their points
output = dict((stat, p_to_v[point]) for stat, point in input.items()) # {'strength':5, 'wits':6}
```

If you want your 'translator' to take less manual work and scale better then you can pre-generate it via some code, depending on your logic of points to values.

Comment: Thank you, this does look faster, and I will put it in the program to do some speed tests agains the other one. Also the idea of a translator is helpful, but the current answer helped me understand the differences I was struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error, here's a one-liner function:

```
def convert(x):
    return x - (x > 4) - (x > 6) - (x > 8) * (x - 8) + (x > 10) + (x > 13)
```

Here's a test:

```
print([(points, convert(points)) for points in range(20)])
# [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 6), (9, 6), (10, 6), (11, 7), (12, 7), (13, 7), (14, 8), (15, 8), (16, 8), (17, 8), (18, 8), (19, 8)]
```

`if` and `elif` statements might be clearer, though.

This function simply converts an amount of input points to a value. You can apply the `convert` function to each element of a list.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but the other one helps me understand what I needed to change and gave me the clearer solution.